# Изменение значения в input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как умножить значение в input на 100?

```js
     $(function(){
      let input = $('#test'),
          inpVal = input.val();
           
      $('.select').on('change', function(){
      
        input.val(inpVal + $(this).val());
      
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select">
  <option value="1">Один</option>
  <option value="2">Два</option>
  <option value="3">Три</option>
  <option value="4">Четыре</option>
  <option value="5">Пять</option>
  <option value="6">Шесть</option>
</select><br />
<input type='text' id='test' value='' />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
input.val(inpVal.val() * 100);
```

---

> как сделать чтобы значение из select отображалось сразу при загрузке
> страницы

```
  $('.select').on('change', function(){
    ...
  }).change();
```

Comment: спасибо, а как сделать чтобы значение из select отображалось сразу при загрузке страницы?

Comment: @user402416 Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.